# native build qt5.7.1 on raspberry pi get errors: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to `QV8Engine::toVariant

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi

i tried to build qt 5.7.1 on pi3 following this instruction:
https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt_5.4.1_on_a_Raspberry_Pi

the source package i use is:
qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1.tar

configure as:

./configure -v -opengl es2 -force-pkg-config -device linux-rpi3-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/ -opensource -confirm-license -optimized-qmake -reduce-exports -release -qt-pcre -qt-xcb -make libs -no-use-gold-linker  -prefix /usr/local/qt5

The instruction is using "linux-rasp-pi-g++", but i think it should be linux-rpi3-g++ for Rpi3.

Make, and i get errors like:

> /usr/bin/g++ -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/vc/lib
>   -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -Wl,-rpath-link,/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -mfloat-abi=hard -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-z,origin -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtdeclarative/lib
>   -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtbase/lib
>   -o ../../bin/qmltestrunner .obj/main.o   -L/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtdeclarative/lib
>   -lQt5QuickTest -L/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtbase/lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Qml -lQt5Network -lQt5Test -lQt5Core -lGLESv2 -lpthread  /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to `QV8Engine::toVariant(QV4::ValueRef, int)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QQmlProfilerService::dataReady(QQmlAbstractProfilerAdapter*)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QV4::ExecutionContext::throwTypeError()'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QV4::Object::markObjects(QV4::Managed*, QV4::ExecutionEngine*)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QQmlEngineDebugService::instance()'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QV8Engine::fromVariant(QVariant const&)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QV4::PersistentValue::operator=(unsigned long long)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QQmlValueType::qt_metacast(char const*)'
>   /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtdeclarative/lib/libQt5QuickTest.so: undefined reference to `QQuickItem::y() const@Qt_5'
>   /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtdeclarative/lib/libQt5QuickTest.so: undefined reference to`QQuickView::errors() const@Qt_5'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QV4::Managed::engine() const'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QV4::ExecutionEngine::newErrorObject(QV4::ValueRef)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QQmlBinding::property() const'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QQmlCustomParser::bindingIdentifier(QV4::CompiledData::Binding
>   const*)' /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined
>   reference to `QV4::ExecutionContext::throwError(QString const&)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QQmlBinding::Invalid' /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5:
>   undefined reference to `QQmlAbstractBinding::vTables'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QV4::ExecutionContext::throwError(QV4::ValueRef)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QV4::Object::call(QV4::Managed*, QV4::CallData*)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QQmlBinding::createBinding(int, QObject*, QQmlContext*)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QV4::Managed::operator new(unsigned int, QV4::MemoryManager*)'
>   /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtdeclarative/lib/libQt5QuickTest.so: undefined reference to`QQuickItem::height() const@Qt_5'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QV4::Object::setLookup(QV4::Managed*, QV4::Lookup*, QV4::ValueRef)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QV4::PersistentValue::PersistentValue(QV4::ValueRef)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QQmlValueType::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QQmlProfilerService::addGlobalProfiler(QQmlAbstractProfilerAdapter*)'
>   /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtdeclarative/lib/libQt5QuickTest.so: undefined reference to `QQuickView::QQuickView(QWindow*)@Qt_5'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QV4::Object::putIndexed(QV4::Managed*, unsigned int, QV4::ValueRef)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QV4::Object::put(QV4::Managed*, QV4::StringRef, QV4::ValueRef)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QV4::Object::Object(QV4::ExecutionEngine*)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QQmlValueType::staticMetaObject'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QShortcutMap::tryShortcutEvent(QObject*, QKeyEvent*)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QQmlProfilerService::instance()'
>   /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtdeclarative/lib/libQt5QuickTest.so: undefined reference to`QQuickView::engine() const@Qt_5'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QV4::Object::getLookup(QV4::Managed*, QV4::Lookup*)'
>   /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtdeclarative/lib/libQt5QuickTest.so: undefined reference to`QQuickView::setSource(QUrl const&)@Qt_5'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QV4::PersistentValue::operator=(QV4::ValueRef)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QV4::ArrayData::realloc(QV4::Object*, QV4::ArrayData::Type, unsigned
>   int, unsigned int, bool)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QQmlInspectorService::addView(QObject*)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QQmlPropertyPrivate::setBinding(QQmlProperty const&,
>   QQmlAbstractBinding*, QFlags)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QQmlComponentPrivate::initializeObjectWithInitialProperties(QV4::ValueRef,
>   QV4::ValueRef, QObject*)'
>   /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtdeclarative/lib/libQt5QuickTest.so: undefined reference to`QQuickItem::staticMetaObject@Qt_5'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QQmlValueType::QQmlValueType(int, QObject*)'
>   /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtdeclarative/lib/libQt5QuickTest.so: undefined reference to`QQuickItem::x() const@Qt_5'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QQmlDebugStream::QQmlDebugStream(QByteArray*,
>   QFlags<QIODevice::OpenModeFlag>)'
>   /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtdeclarative/lib/libQt5QuickTest.so: undefined reference to`QQuickItem::window() const@Qt_5'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QV4::Object::~Object()'
>   /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtdeclarative/lib/libQt5QuickTest.so: undefined reference to`QQuickItem::mapToScene(QPointF const&)
>   const@Qt_5' /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined
>   reference to `QV4::Object::deleteProperty(QV4::Managed*,
>   QV4::StringRef)'
>   /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtdeclarative/lib/libQt5QuickTest.so: undefined reference to`QQuickView::rootContext() const@Qt_5'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QV4::Object::getIndexed(QV4::Managed*, unsigned int, bool*)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QQmlDebugService::isDebuggingEnabled()'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QV4::Object::destroy(QV4::Managed*)'
>   /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtdeclarative/lib/libQt5QuickTest.so: undefined reference to`QQuickWindow::grabWindow()@Qt_5'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QQmlValueType::metaObject() const'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QQmlAbstractBinding::weakPointer()'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QV4::Object::get(QV4::Managed*, QV4::StringRef, bool*)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QOpenGLContextPrivate::globalShareContext()'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QV4::Managed::setVTable(QV4::ManagedVTable const*)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QQmlEngineDebugService::setStatesDelegate(QQmlDebugStatesDelegate*)'
>   /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtdeclarative/lib/libQt5QuickTest.so: undefined reference to `QQuickView::status() const@Qt_5'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QV4::Object::construct(QV4::Managed*, QV4::CallData*)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QQmlInspectorService::instance()'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QV4::Object::query(QV4::Managed const*, QV4::StringRef)'
>   /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtdeclarative/lib/libQt5QuickTest.so: undefined reference to `QQuickItem::width() const@Qt_5'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QV4::Object::defineAccessorProperty(QV4::StringRef, unsigned long
>   long (*)(QV4::CallContext*), unsigned long long
>   (*)(QV4::CallContext*))'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QV4::Object::advanceIterator(QV4::Managed*, QV4::ObjectIterator*,
>   QV4::StringRef, unsigned int*, QV4::Property*,
>   QV4::PropertyAttributes*)'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   QV4::String::simplifyString() const'
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `QQmlInspectorService::removeView(QObject*)' collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status Makefile:108: recipe for target
>   '../../bin/qmltestrunner' failed make[3]: ***
>   [../../bin/qmltestrunner] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory
>   '/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtdeclarative/tools/qmltestrunner'
>   Makefile:276: recipe for target 'sub-qmltestrunner-make_first' failed
>   make[2]: *** [sub-qmltestrunner-make_first] Error 2

so, how can i fix this problem?

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this problem, and there is a new problem now.

Before native building qt on pi, I installed qt by: 
sudo apt-get install qt5-default, and other qt5 packages.

Although I have : 
  sudo apt-get remove those packages, it may still works.

so I formatted the SD card and re-burned an Raspbian image, followed the instructions, "make", and the problem is gone.

but now I have another problem.

When I "make install", I get this error:

/usr/bin/g++ -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/vc/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -Wl,-rpath-link,/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -mfloat-abi=hard -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-z,origin -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../../lib -shared -o libdeclarative_location.so .obj/location.o .obj/qdeclarativegeomapitemview.o .obj/qdeclarativegeoserviceprovider.o .obj/qdeclarativegeocodemodel.o .obj/qdeclarativegeoroutemodel.o .obj/qdeclarativegeoroute.o .obj/qdeclarativegeoroutesegment.o .obj/qdeclarativegeomaneuver.o .obj/qdeclarativegeomap.o .obj/qdeclarativegeomaptype.o .obj/qdeclarativegeomapitembase.o .obj/qdeclarativegeomapquickitem.o .obj/qdeclarativecirclemapitem.o .obj/qdeclarativerectanglemapitem.o .obj/qdeclarativepolygonmapitem.o .obj/qdeclarativepolylinemapitem.o .obj/qdeclarativeroutemapitem.o .obj/qgeomapitemgeometry.o .obj/qdeclarativegeomapcopyrightsnotice.o .obj/error_messages.o .obj/locationvaluetypehelper.o .obj/qquickgeomapgesturearea.o .obj/qquickgeocoordinateanimation.o .obj/mapitemviewdelegateincubator.o .obj/qdeclarativeplacecontentmodel.o .obj/qdeclarativesupportedcategoriesmodel.o .obj/qdeclarativesearchsuggestionmodel.o .obj/qdeclarativesearchresultmodel.o .obj/qdeclarativereviewmodel.o .obj/qdeclarativeplaceimagemodel.o .obj/qdeclarativeplaceeditorialmodel.o .obj/qdeclarativecontactdetail.o .obj/qdeclarativecategory.o .obj/qdeclarativeplace.o .obj/qdeclarativeplaceattribute.o .obj/qdeclarativeplaceicon.o .obj/qdeclarativeplaceuser.o .obj/qdeclarativeratings.o .obj/qdeclarativesupplier.o .obj/qdeclarativesearchmodelbase.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativecirclemapitem_p.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativerectanglemapitem_p.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativepolygonmapitem_p.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativepolylinemapitem_p.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativeroutemapitem_p.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativegeomapcopyrightsnotice_p.o .obj/moc_qquickgeocoordinateanimation_p.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativeplacecontentmodel.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativesupportedcategoriesmodel_p.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativesearchsuggestionmodel_p.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativesearchresultmodel_p.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativereviewmodel_p.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativeplaceimagemodel_p.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativeplaceeditorialmodel.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativecontactdetail_p.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativecategory_p.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativeplace_p.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativeplaceattribute_p.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativeplaceicon_p.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativeplaceuser_p.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativeratings_p.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativesupplier_p.o .obj/moc_qdeclarativesearchmodelbase.o  -L=/opt/vc/lib -L/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtlocation/lib -lQt5Location -L/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtbase/lib -L/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtdeclarative/lib -lQt5Quick -lQt5Gui -lQt5Qml -lQt5Network -lQt5Positioning -lQt5Core -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/vc/lib -lGLESv2 -lpthread -lclip2tri -L/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtlocation/lib -lpoly2tri -lclipper

**/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclip2tri**

**/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpoly2tri**

**/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclipper**

**collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

Makefile:273: recipe for target '../../../qml/QtLocation/libdeclarative_location.so' failed

make[4]: *** [../../../qml/QtLocation/libdeclarative_location.so] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtlocation/src/imports/location'

Makefile:80: recipe for target 'sub-location-install_subtargets' failed

make[3]: *** [sub-location-install_subtargets] Error 2

make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtlocation/src/imports'

Makefile:135: recipe for target 'sub-imports-install_subtargets' failed

make[2]: *** [sub-imports-install_subtargets] Error 2

make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtlocation/src'

Makefile:56: recipe for target 'sub-src-install_subtargets' failed

make[1]: *** [sub-src-install_subtargets] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtlocation'

Makefile:844: recipe for target 'module-qtlocation-install_subtargets' failed

make: *** [module-qtlocation-install_subtargets] Error 2

I found there are 3 directories in qtlocation/src/3rdparty

```
clip2tri
clipper
poly2tri
```

and 3 file in qtlocation/lib:

```
libclip2tri.prl
libclipper.prl
libpoly2tri.prl
```

but no lib files.

I checked the build log, it seems cpp file in the directoriy qtlocation/src/3rdparty are not compiled,

cd 3rdparty/ && ( test -e Makefile || /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtbase/bin/qmake /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtlocation/src/3rdparty/3rdparty.pro -qtconf /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile install
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtlocation/src/3rdparty'

cd poly2tri/ && ( test -e Makefile || /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtbase/bin/qmake /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtlocation/src/3rdparty/poly2tri/poly2tri.pro -qtconf /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile install

make[4]: Entering directory '/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/**qtlocation/src/3rdparty/poly2tri**'

make[4]: **Nothing to be done for 'install'**.

make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/**qtlocation/src/3rdparty/poly2tri**'

cd clipper/ && ( test -e Makefile || /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtbase/bin/qmake /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtlocation/src/3rdparty/clipper/clipper.pro -qtconf /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile install

make[4]: Entering directory '/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/**qtlocation/src/3rdparty/clipper'**

make[4]: **Nothing to be done for 'install'**.

make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/**qtlocation/src/3rdparty/clipper'**

cd clip2tri/ && ( test -e Makefile || /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtbase/bin/qmake /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtlocation/src/3rdparty/clip2tri/clip2tri.pro -qtconf /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile install

make[4]: Entering directory '/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/**qtlocation/src/3rdparty/clip2tri'**

make[4]: **Nothing to be done for 'install'.**

make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtlocation/src/3rdparty/clip2tri'

make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtlocation/src/3rdparty'

cd location/ && ( test -e Makefile || /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtbase/bin/qmake /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtlocation/src/location/location.pro -qtconf /home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile install
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/download/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/qtlocation/src/location'

Comment: Are you building Qt from sources or using packages shipped with raspbian?

Comment: I saw the same issue while building Qt-5.9.1 on RH6.5. For the 3 missing library I went to those dirs and manually run make. After that everything went fine.